# Python % "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python, string, module

I am a newbie and this is my first exposure to python so please be kind.

Here is my code:

```
days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def doomsday_func(year):
    c = str(year)[:2]
    a = (5((c % 4) + 2) % 7)
    return(days[a])

print(doomsday_func(1954))
```

I am trying to use the doomsday algorithm. My first task is to complete a function that returns the anchor day from the formula a=(5(cmod4)+2)mod7
a=(5(cmod4)+2)mod7. I am being met with "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting". I know it is because the print(doomsday_function(year)) will return a string and has something to do with my % operator. I have tried putting int in various combinations around my a = line and cannot figure this out.

Comment: `str(year)[:2]` is not a number. It's a *string*.

Comment: Debugger  -what fancy tools to use ... breakpoint on line, inspect variable, gotcha error.

Comment: Could you please clarify? I am still not understanding.

Adding int(str(year)[:2] I get "int" object is not callable

Comment: `c = str(year)[:2]` will make `c` a string. What do you expect `some_string % 4` to do? I'll give you a hint - it isn't the `mod` operation. Also note, in Python, `(...)` is the *function call operator*. so `5(...)` is **not** "5 multiply whatever is in parentheses", it's "5 call whatever is in parentheses", which will give you another error, telling you that `int` objects (like `5`) are not callable. If you want multiplication, you need to use the multiplication operator, `5*(...)`

Comment: The modulo operator acts differently on strings vs integers `19 % 4` gives `3`.  `'19' % 4` gives a TypeError because modulo on strings is for string interpolation.  It's typically used like `'blah: %s' % 35` which would give `'blah: 35'` or `'%s  %s' % ('x', 'y')` resulting in `'x  y'`.  In your case you gave one argument but had no formatting specifiers inside your string.  So wrong number of arguments.

Comment: Note that when you finally do make `c` an `int` this `(5((c % 4) + 2) % 7)` will still fail because `5(` will try to call an `int` and integers are not callable.  Perhaps you mean to multiply by 5?  Then do  `(5 * ((c % 4) + 2) % 7)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @StevenRumbalski and juan

Through some more effort I feel I am very close.

days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]
def doomsday_func(year):
    c = (str(year)[:2])
    a = (5*(((int(c) % 4) + 2))) % 7
    return(days[a])

print(doomsday_func(1954))

It is returning Thursday though when my example problem clearly shows the answer is (3) "Wednesday" I am unsure what part I am missing.


Edit: This was basic PEMDAS. 
Problem solved. Thanks for the help and patience.

Comment: I'm glad I have linked to a Q&A I answered to: got me a downvote on my answer :) next time I'll vote as "unclear" instead.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Good duplicate.  Problem remedied.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yes, exact duplicate. Thanks